# Check Triangle Type in Java

Tags: java

I don't know what's wrong with my code, I think I have something wrong with my if statments! Please check the code below;

---

```
package triangle2;
import java.util.*;
public class Triangle2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the sides of Triangle");
int a = sc.nextInt();
int b = sc.nextInt();
int c = sc.nextInt(); 
if (a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0)
System.out.println("InvalidInput");
if(a >= (b+c) || c >= (b+a) || b >= (a+c) )
System.out.println("Not a Triangle");
if(a==b && b==c)
System.out.println("Equilateral Triangle");
else if (((a * a) + (b * b)) == (c * c) || ((a * a) + (c * c)) == (b * b) || ((c * c) + (b * b)) == (a * a))
System.out.println("Right Triangle");
else if(a!=b && b!=c && c!=a)
System.out.println("Scalene Triangle");
else if ((a==b && b!=c ) || (a!=b && c==a) || (c==b && c!=a))
System.out.println("Isosceles Triangle");
}   
}
```

Also, I tried the following but still I couldn't solve it! I created a method to check the triangle and then I had an object from Triangle class on the main but still. I think it's from the if and elseif.
    package triangle;
    import java.util.*;

```
class Triangle {
int a,b,c;

public Triangle(){
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the sides of Triangle");
try{
int a = sc.nextInt();
int b = sc.nextInt();
int c = sc.nextInt();
}
catch(InputMismatchException ime){
System.out.println("Error: your value must be an integer!");
}
if (a <= 0 || b <= 0 || c <= 0)
System.out.println("InvalidInput");  
}

public void CheckTriangle(){ 
int triType = 0;
if(a >= (b+c) || c >= (b+a) || b >= (a+c) )
System.out.println( "Not a Triangle");
else if(a==b && b==c)
System.out.println( "Equilateral Triangle");
else if (((a * a) + (b * b)) == (c * c) || ((a * a) + (c * c)) == (b * b) || ((c * c) + (b * b)) == (a * a))
System.out.println( "Right Triangle");
else if(a!=b && b!=c && c!=a)
System.out.println( "Scalene Triangle" );
else if ((a==b && b!=c ) || (a!=b && c==a) || (c==b && c!=a))
System.out.println( "Isosceles Triangle");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Triangle t=new Triangle();
t.CheckTriangle();
}
}
```

Comment: Please describe what problems do you encounter. Compile errors? Runtime errors? No errors, but the result is different than what you expect?

Comment: I am trying to ask the user for the Triangle sides! then depending on these sides I want to print the type of this triangle! but it still printing "Not a Triangle" whith every side I test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is correct, the reason it was printing "Not a triangle" at every test is because you were not stopping it after finding a invalid triangle, this should work for you :

```
if(a<=0 || b<=0 || c<=0)
    System.out.println("InvalidInput");
else if(a>=(b+c) || c>=(b+a) || b>=(a+c))
    System.out.println("Not a Triangle");
else if(a==b && b==c)
    System.out.println("Equilateral Triangle");
else if(((a*a)+(b*b))==(c*c) || ((a*a)+(c*c))==(b*b) || ((c*c)+(b*b))==(a*a))
    System.out.println("Right Triangle");
else if(a!=b && b!=c && c!=a)
    System.out.println("Scalene Triangle");
else if(a==b || c==a || c==b)
    System.out.println("Isosceles Triangle");
```

**Note:** I slightly optimized the last condition, since you are using an if/else, some of the conditions were already tested and will always be `true` at that point of the program.
For example : in `(a==b && b!=c )`, the condition `b!=c` has already been verified in the previous case (the "Scalene Triangle" test).

### EDIT:

To make sure inputs are numbers, simply surround your code in a `Try/Catch` block :

```
System.out.println("Enter the sides of Triangle");
try
{
    int a=sc.nextInt();
    int b=sc.nextInt();
    int c=sc.nextInt();
    if(a<=0 || b<=0 || c<=0)
        System.out.println("InvalidInput");
    else if(a >= (b+c) || c >= (b+a) || b >= (a+c))
        System.out.println("Not a Triangle");
    else if(a==b && b==c)
        System.out.println("Equilateral Triangle");
    else if(((a*a)+(b*b))==(c*c) || ((a*a)+(c*c))==(b*b) || ((c*c)+(b*b))==(a*a))
        System.out.println("Right Triangle");
    else if(a!=b && b!=c && c!=a)
        System.out.println("Scalene Triangle");
    else if(a==b || c==a || c==b)
        System.out.println("Isosceles Triangle");
} catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Error: enter a number!");
}
```

**TEST**

[image]

Comment: Thaaaaank you, a small word can affect the whole code. How can I print invalid error while the user trying to write a String.

Comment: @Allo0o2a, You can use a `Try\Catch` to handle exceptions, I edited my answer to add more details  :)

Comment: Thank you very much. You know I tried Try/Catch before the variable and they became hiddin from the rest of the code! Then I tried Try/Catch before the if statments and still the code get confused! I didn't think about putting the whole code in Try/Catch. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

I used your logic, but re-organized into a proper class structure and it works fine for me.

```
public class Triangle {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;

    public Triangle(int a, int b, int c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void determineType() {
        if(a >= (b+c) || c >= (b+a) || b >= (a+c) ) {
            System.out.println( "Not a Triangle");
        } else if(a==b && b==c) {
            System.out.println( "Equilateral Triangle");
        } else if (((a * a) + (b * b)) == (c * c) || ((a * a) + (c * c)) == (b * b) || ((c * c) + (b * b)) == (a * a)) {
            System.out.println( "Right Triangle");
        } else if(a!=b && b!=c && c!=a) {
            System.out.println( "Scalene Triangle" );
        } else if ((a==b && b!=c ) || (a!=b && c==a) || (c==b && c!=a)) {
            System.out.println( "Isosceles Triangle");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the sides of Triangle");
        int a = in.nextInt();
        int b = in.nextInt();
        int c = in.nextInt();
        Triangle t = new Triangle(a, b, c);
        t.determineType();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan! your code is working, I didn't think about creat a constructor.

Comment: Can you assist on testing using assertEqual?